# "no alive nodes found in cluster" while indexing docs

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a "legacy" php application that we just migrated to run on Google Cloud (Kubernetes Engine).  Along with it I also have a ElasticSearch installation (Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes) running. After a few incidents with Kubernetes killing my Elastic Search when we're trying to deploy other services we have come to the conclusion that we should probably not run ES on Kubernetes, at least if are to manage it ourselves. This due to a apparent lack of knowledge for doing it in a robust way.

So our idea is now to move to managed Elastic Cloud instead which was really simple to deploy and start using. However... now that I try to load ES with the data needed for our php application if fails mid-process with the error message `no alive nodes found in cluster`. Sometimes it happens after less than 1000 "documents" and other times I manage to get 5000+ of them indexed before failure.

This is how I initialize the es client:

```
$clientBuilder = ClientBuilder::create();
$clientBuilder->setElasticCloudId(ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID);
$clientBuilder->setBasicAuthentication('elastic',ELASTICSEARCH_PW);
$clientBuilder->setRetries(10);

$this->esClient = $clientBuilder->build();
```

`ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID` & `ELASTICSEARCH_PW` are set via environment vars.

The request looks something like:

```
$params = [
    'index' => $index,  
    'type' => '_doc',
    'body' => $body,
    'client' => [
      'timeout' => 15,
      'connect_timeout' => 30,
      'curl' => [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-type: application/json']
]
```

The body and which index depends on how far we get with the "ingestion", but generally pretty standard stuff.

All this works without any real problems when running on a own installation of Elastic in our own GKE cluster.

What I've tried so far is to add the retries and timeouts, but none of that seems to make much of a difference?

We're running:

- php 7.4
- ElasticSearch 7.11
- Elastic Search client 7.12 (php via composer)

Answer (score 1):

If you use WAMP64, this error will occur, You have to use XAMPP instead.

Try the following command in the command prompt, If it runs, there is a problem with your configurations.

```
curl -u elastic:<password> https://<endpoint>:<port>
```

(Ex for Elastic Cloud)

```
curl -u elastic:<password> example.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9234
```

Comment: Can you please explain it?